# How do I create an Intelligent Input Field field that suggests word for Autocompletion using python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am creating a Dictionary and I want to create an Input Field using :

```
Tk.Entry()
```

And I want this input field to be intelligent such that when I am typing in a word, Lets say I type 'F' , then It will list all the words that i have in my dictionary that start with F :

```
Eg: 
    Fantastic
    Fun
    Fundamental, etc...
```

So I can now select the word i want from the list and It will display the meaning.

Or If I type 'Fu' in the search box, then it will only display 'Fun' and 'Fundamental'

Please How do I do this.

I already know how to create a normal python dictionary app using Tkinter by storing my words and meanings in a json file and reading it in my script. But I want to add this function to make it a little bit intelligent like how google suggests word before you finish typing your search. Please how do i do this??

Please I need a hint from someone or link to any video or PDF that will teach me about this

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a good starting point:

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578253-an-entry-with-autocompletion-for-the-tkinter-gui/

This method use `Listbox()` as dropdown menu, and updates its content based on what text is entered.